# Angular; Are deeply nested modules a good idea?

Tags: angular

In short, are deeply nested Angular modules a good idea? I appreciate it maybe subjective but looking for advice from peeps with more experience than I. For example;

If I wish to create a "forum" module and inside the module will be a lot of functionality requirements for threads, posts and lots of other crazy stuff I build, should I create a nested module for "posts" (for example) which is imported into the forum module and in turn imported into the app module? I'm concerned that my forum module will become bloated.

Comment: There are no nested modules in Angular, only modules, that import other modules.

Comment: How can forum module be not 'bloated' if a forum consists of threads and posts by design? If these items are unique and aren't supposed to be reused anywhere else, they probably don't need their own modules. Or probably do.

Answer (score 1):

Of course it's okay. It's designed to work like this.
`Your initial app has only a single module, the root module. As your app grows, you'll consider subdividing it into multiple "feature" modules, some of which can be loaded later ("lazy loaded") if and when the user chooses to visit those features.`

```
Modules are a great way to organize an application and extend 
it with capabilities from external libraries.

Many Angular libraries are modules (such as FormsModule, HttpModule, and 
RouterModule). Many third-party libraries are available as NgModules (such 
as Material Design, Ionic, AngularFire2).

NgModules consolidate components, directives, and pipes into cohesive blocks 
of functionality, each focused on a feature area, application business 
domain, workflow, or common collection of utilities.
```

https://angular.io/guide/ngmodule

https://angular.io/guide/bootstrapping

Answer (score 0):

I have found that when the number of a component's children components gets too high (or above a limit i or the team lead set) i create a new more specific component for the case.

For example i had an address-block component that eventually (due to many work streams needing it for different uses) the component was MASSIVE and had a lot of children within it. 
To tackle this, i stripped the address block out to what it originally was for and took the individual user cases that were originally placed within address-block and made them their own components for example

All i can say is, nesting IS FINE but beware! having many nested components relying on data or bindings from parent components (sometimes more than one parent component) can be FIDDLY AS HELL not to mention the frustration it can bring.